# Check a textbox for some certain text asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, textbox

How do I check if a textbox contains "@mediacollege.dk" in like this

```
if (email.text == "here it checks if it contains "@mediacollege.dk" and does a command")
{
    DHF_LodderTableAdapter DHFLodder = new DHF_LodderTableAdapter();
    DHFLodder.Insert(UserName.Text, 10);
}
else
{
    // nothing
}
```

Comment: String.Contains Mehtod: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as

```
if (email.text.Contains("@mediacollege.dk") )
 {
        // do your work
     DHF_LodderTableAdapter DHFLodder = new DHF_LodderTableAdapter();
     DHFLodder.Insert(UserName.Text, 10);    
}
else
{
    // nothing
}
```